# Oops, an error occurred - after TYPO3 Upgrade 7.6 to 8.7

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I tried manually upgrade TYPO3 from 7.6.6 to 8.7.16 and received: *Oops, an error occurred!* I can't login to TYPO3.

I apologize for the brief description but I was very tired after a many hours trying to remove the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dfve.jpg). The error looks just like the image, but at the beginning there was a white screen ...

Over the years I have not had problems installing TYPO3 (still Versions 3 and 4), but I had a break in use. I do not have access to SSH. I also assume Symlink was mistakenly set by the admin, and that's why I had to do it manually.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html

Similarly, because I did not have access and I did it manually... I noticed that there are also changes in installation, perhaps a problem.

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** and requires **urgent attention** as you need to give more details with how you manually upgraded Typo3. Also, if possible, you need to copy the detailed explanation of the error.

Comment: please set 'config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0' in your root template to get a more expressive error message. We still need more information for helping you.

Comment: @Mulliganaceous the problem was in fact described very short, because the visible output is exactly like that. The hint of Robert might help but perhaps even not in all cases.

Comment: Still think you could make your description better: What steps did you do? Did you execute the Upgrade Wizard? Did you follow suggestion by Robert? Which error message did you get?

Answer (score 2):

First step to do after an upgrade is to open the install-tool primary to alter tables for new requirements:

```
example.com/typo3/install.php
```

There you have to open the upgrade-wizard and follow the shown steps.

You also get the option shown to install `compatibility-7`, an extension that adds a compatibility-layer for older extensions. You can enter that step and afterwards still decide if to install it or not. In the wizard the logic is that the option will be shown and no matter about your decision it will be marked as `done`, so that it won't be shown another time again usually.

In your case it's better to follow the update-instructions rather than the install-instructions: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/Upgrade/Index.html